# Mulesoft download zip file via APIKit Router

Tags: anypoint-studio, apikit

I am having trouble with browser showing save/download prompt for zip file on http endpoint wiht APIKit Router.

I have a sub flow that gets S3 object and sets payload to #[message.payload.getObjectContent] which works fine with http listener going straight to flow, but if using APIKit router browser returns nothing.

I think it might have something to do with my raml.

```
/GetPackage
  get:
    responses:
      200:
        description: Success
        body:
          200:
            application/zip
```

I also read something about...

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=file.zip
```

Some help/direction would be much appreciated

Tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution. It wasn't enough just having `application/zip` in RAML.

Needed to set two properties in Flow (with Property component):

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=filename.zip
Content-Type: application/zip
```

Configuration XML that I used:

```
<set-property propertyName="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=filename.zip" doc:name="Content-Disposition"/>
<set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/zip" doc:name="Content-Type"/>
```